# C - How to read a string with only spaces using scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm with a little problem while doing an excercise to learn C.
The problem is: I need to read a string from the user, but if he types just a space, I need to print a space. That's okay in theory.
But, when I type the space while the program is running, it doesn't understand it as a string and it keeps waiting for me to type other things.

I'm using the `scanf("%[^\n]", string_name_here);`

I appreciate your help, and have a nice day! o/
And sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand this :)

Comment: push enter because `stdin` is bufferd stream. or add limit like this `"%10[^\n]"`

Comment: Stop using scanf.  If you want to learn C, read input using `fgetc`, `fread`, `fgets`, and `read`.  (Maybe a few others).

Comment: And a reasonable argument could be made to avoid `read`

Answer (score 1):

Using `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` will make your day.

According to man :

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>   A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

**Example program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSTR 21

int main(void)
{
char my_str[MAXSTR] = {'\0'};

fgets(my_str, MAXSTR, stdin);

return 0;
}
```

**Input :**

> Claudio Cortese

**Output :**

> Claudio Cortese